# Can the Snake example be easily converted to Touchpad?

Tags: java, android

I'm practicing with the Snake example from the Android SDK, and I feel I fully understand this example. I want to convert this example so it actually works on a touch-screen Android.

In a perfect world, I'd like to see an example where the `onKeyDown` could simply be replaced with [whatever touch handler].

And then I would convert, for example, the `KeEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP` to whatever the swipe-up counterpart is, etc.

Is it that easy, or does this thing have to be re-written from the ground up to support touchpad?  If it's that easy, can you point me in the right direction with a simple generic example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be difficult. You have to add the OnGestureListener interface to your activity or to the view that handles the keyPadEvents.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html

The interface requires the implementation of public abstract methods,e.g. `onDown(MotionEvent e)`, etc.

Where you can copy the code into that formerly was in `onKeyDown`

Comment: P6, thank you.  I'm trying to work with that and am having mixed success--but that got me pushed in the right direction, I will get there eventually.